# Go SQL syntax error

Tags: postgresql, go, syntax-error, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert a row into a Postgres table using [`database/sql`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/). The code I'm running looks like

```
...
res, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO image(name) VALUES(?);", fname)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
...
```

`fname` is a string. Something like `"image-name.png"`. The `image` table was created by the statement

```
...
_, err := db.Exec("CREATE TABLE image (id SERIAL, name VARCHAR)")
...
```

After running that `CREATE TABLE` statement, I'm able to hop into `psql` and manually run

```
INSERT INTO image(name) VALUES('some-random-image.jpg');
```

with the appropriate row being added to the `image` table. However, the `INSERT` `Exec` call above consistently errors with `pq: syntax error at or near ")"`.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, as a follow-up, is there any way to see the result of statement formatting in `go`? I'm thinking of something like `func Preview (template string, args...) string` such that

```
Preview("INSERT INTO tbl(col) VALUES(?);", "test")
   => "INSERT INTO tbl(col) VALUES('test');"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use $1, $2, ... as placeholder values in your SQL. The placeholder characters are DB dependent and for Postgres they are `$X`.